# Hydrogen permeation from low to high absolute pressure area due to difference in partial pressure?

Tags: thermodynamics, diffusion

I need to get help with a question regarding hydrogen permeation which I do not really how to get around.

The statement is as following:
A steel container contains helium gas at high pressure (100 bara). Surrounding it is hydrogen gas at a lower pressure (approx. 3 bara) and at a great volume. Hydrogen can permeate the steel walls of the helium container but helium is impermeable through steel. After infinite time, will the pressure increase, decrease or stay the same within the helium container?

I am a bit puzzled about this. There is a concentration gradient and a gradient in partial pressure of hydrogen, but on the other hand, there is a much higher pressure inside the helium container. Is permeation driven by concentration gradient or "mechanical" flux/mass flow?

Hope someone got an easy answer for me, because this is keeping me up at night. Thank you all in advance!

Comment: The He cannot escape, so the pressure cannot go down, so it is either constant or increases. The partial pressure of H2 is initially zero inside so diffusion will occur until the H2 pressures are equal. Consider how could the He prevent the H2 from diffusing.

Comment: Porphyrin is right. But does it make sense to make a statement that steel is permeable to hydrogen and not to helium ? Both have about the same dimension. I would have been less dubious if the inner gas was $\ce{CO2}$ or $\ce{CH4}$

Comment: Hydrogen can permeate a steel barrier, which helium cannot. As hydrogen can move as free ions through the lattice structure.

Comment: Related to a manufacturer who filled tennis balls with sulfur hexafluoride, so the balls would stay “fresh” on the store shelves. Then no need for pressurized tennis ball cans, so less expense. But air diffused into the balls faster than the sulfur hexafluoride diffused out of them, so the pressure kept increasing and tennis balls randomly exploded (“loudly burst”) on the store shelves.

Comment: @Ed V, great comment really made me laugh!